# Is it possible to adjust these FFmpeg settings to make this as CPU friendly as possible

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i https://NESTCAMURL -vf drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%T}':fontcolor=white@0.8:x=7:y=700 -vcodec libx264 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc /home/owner/Downloads/Move/NEST/Livingroom/StreamLivingroom_$now.mp4"
```

The above command seems to max out the CPU and ideally I would like it to use as little resources as possible while still achieving decent video quality. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

"as little resources as possible while still achieving decent video quality" Is like saying use as little fuel as possible, but drive far enough. The efficiency can not be changed, You need to decide how much quality you are willing to give up. You can make the tradeoff by setting x264 presets.

EDIT:
Try adding `-crf 18 -preset ultrafast` The cost will be a larger file size.

Comment: I need enough quality to identify someone if they decide to break into the house. So I guess 480p would do the trick? The command I use right now however involves -c copy and uses little to no CPU resources, is there anyway to overlay video timestamp while avoiding transcoding. Using subtitles has been recommended on another site, but idk if its possible or even how.

Comment: Quality and resolution are not necessarily the same thing. You can have a blurry image at 1080p. But downscaling will make the encode faster (fewer pixels to encode) But the scaling operation will take CPU as well. No. It is not possible to change the pixel values (overlay) without transcoding. `-vf scale=640:480 -crf 18 -preset ultrafast` is about as fast as you can get. I would also recommend adding `-re` before `-i` if this is live video. You can also try another codec like mpeg2 or mjpeg that will be faster, but take more disk space.

Comment: Additional note: using mp4 to record live video, you are likely to get corrupted unusable files if not very careful how FFmpeg exits. Use flv or mkv instead so the entire video is not corrupted on errors.

Answer (score 0):

> “The above command seems to max out the CPU and ideally I would like it to use as little resources as possible while still achieving decent video quality.”

The problem with your logic is that you assume that internal FFmpeg settings are to blame, when they aren’t… Well not exactly, but to be simple and clear about this I will state that pretty much any Linux/Unix system software can be controlled to limit usage with the tool [CPUlimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/):

> **cpulimit** is a simple program which attempts to limit the cpu usage of a process (expressed in **percentage**, not in cpu time). This is useful to control batch jobs, when you don't want them to eat too much cpu. It does not act on the nice value or other scheduling priority stuff, but on the **real** cpu usage. Also, it is able to adapt itself to the overall system load, dynamically and quickly.

So on a most basic level you can run your command using CPUlimit’s `-l` command like this:

```
cpulimit -l 50 ffmpeg -i https://NESTCAMURL -vf drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%T}':fontcolor=white@0.8:x=7:y=700 -vcodec libx264 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc /home/owner/Downloads/Move/NEST/Livingroom/StreamLivingroom_$now.mp4"
```

That `cpulimit -l 50` tells the system to only use 50% of the CPU power so your process will take 2x the time but also use only 50% of CPU resources.

But keep in mind that a 4 core system—like the MacBook Air I am using right now—equate to 400% (4 x 100%). So if I wanted to use only 50% of my system’s available capacity, I would need to run the `-l` flag with 200% capacity like this: `cpulimit -l 200`.

```
cpulimit -l 200 ffmpeg -i https://NESTCAMURL -vf drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%T}':fontcolor=white@0.8:x=7:y=700 -vcodec libx264 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc /home/owner/Downloads/Move/NEST/Livingroom/StreamLivingroom_$now.mp4"
```

For more information, look at [this great blog post as well](http://tuxdiary.com/2014/09/03/cpulimit-taskset/).